# Create a new table from existing table with specific columns and a sequence number (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to create a table in Oracle SQL from an existing table.  I only want to use certain columns, and I want to add a column to the table that is a sequential number.
The original table was created with:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
  (
    FNAME VARCHAR2(15)  NOT NULL,
  MINIT CHAR,
  LNAME VARCHAR2(15)    NOT NULL,
  SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  BDATE DATE,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
  SEX CHAR,
  SALARY NUMBER(10,2),
    SUPER_SSN CHAR(9),
  DNO NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT EMPPK PRIMARY KEY (SSN) DISABLE,
  CONSTRAINT EMPSUPERFK FOREIGN KEY (SUPER_SSN) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN) DISABLE
  );
```

I want to use the FNAME, LNAME, SSN and BDATE columns.  I also want to add a new column, EMP_NUM which is a sequential number starting at 1000.

I was trying:

```
CREATE 
TABLE NEW_EMP
  (EMP_NUM NUMBER)
AS 
SELECT SSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE
  FROM EMPLOYEE
```

But kept getting an error.  Every time I think I've got it, I get an error.  Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate the emp number from a sequence you need to first create a sequence, then use it in the select statement:

```
create sequence seq_emp_num start with 1000;

CREATE TABLE NEW_EMP
AS 
SELECT seq_emp_num.nextval as emp_num, SSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

---

For more details see the manual:

- [how to use sequence values](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50946)
- [create sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314)

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_EMP AS 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPPK) + 999 as EMP_NUM,
       SSN, FNAME, LNAME, BDATE
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

I would be careful about doing this, though.  Your original table has a primary key, so I think that should follow each row around everywhere.  In addition, I see little use for such a table.  You can always generate it easily when you need it, for instance, by using a CTE in a query.

Comment: I'll be honest.  It's for a class, though nowhere in the class was this kind of statement brought up.  The directions say to use CREATE SEQUENCE to create the sequential numbers.  That being said, when I run it, I get "missing SELECT keyword."